# Meaning of each entry in torch.autograd.profiler.profile

Tags: pytorch

All

I just try using the torch.autograd.profiler.profile
There are several entries

```
Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg     Self CUDA   Self CUDA %    CUDA total  CUDA time avg    # of Calls
```

where could I find the explanation for these? does the time calculated in CPU total also overlap with the time in CUDA total if an operator involves the GPU computation?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know where could I find the similar page for CUDA profiling? This one only has the CPU profiling

Comment: I recently came across this, so havent tried it myself, but it has use_cuda option. However its example is not documented in above tutorial. There is also https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/benchmark.html with gpu based profiling but its for a single command/function